# Why C# allowed DateObject.Date.Date.Date.Date?

Tags: c#

See this below code

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
var day = date.Date.Date.Date.Date.Date.Date.Date.Date.Date;
```

Why C# allowed this kind of funny codes? Is it bug?

Same as `Tostring().Tostring().Tostring().Tostring().Tostring().Tostring()`

Comment: Same as `Tostring().Tostring().Tostring().Tostring().Tostring().Tostring()`

Comment: Why would it not allow this? And this is not about a C# language issue but about the design of the DateTime class.

Comment: Apparently it is looking funny but logically not.

Comment: Have you looked at the property signature for `Date` on `DateTime`?

Comment: He, `1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1` still equals one. Why would mathematics allow this? Is something broken in our most fundamental science?

Comment: @HenkHolterman . `1 * 1 * 1` is needed for calculations. But Why I need to use `ToString().ToString().Tostring(`)?

Comment: It is needed to get a string.

Comment: what's the difference between ToString() and ToString().ToString()?

Comment: The same as the difference between `x * 1` and `x * 1 * 1`. You really are looking into a problem that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Date` property of a `DateTime` returns a `DateTime` itself, but with the time set to midnight on the day of the original `DateTime`. Since the returned date does not have a special `Date` type, but is still a `DateTime`, you can keep calling `Date` on it, even though the returned `DateTime` would represent the same date and time in every consecutive call.

As for the `ToString` case mentioned in several comments: Every object in C# implements the `ToString` method as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx). Since a `string` is an object itself and the `ToString` method is implemented for `string`, you can keep calling that one as well. As for the `DateTime` case, all consecutive calls will represent the same value.

Comment: What about the `Tostring().Tostring().Tostring().Tostring().Tostring().Tostring()`?

Comment: @RameshRajendran same story, a string has a ToString itself which you can call.

Comment: @RameshRajendran, see my edit

Comment: To build upon this answer, we can say that the additional `.Date`/`.ToString()` calls are just [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) invocations. You may want to take a look at the mathematical definition and its usage in math. Identity functions are important in programming too, but your example of `.Date.Date.Date` is pretty much artificial.